# Scala parsing package isn't recognized

Tags: eclipse, scala, compiler-errors

I try to import the `scala.util.parsing` library and the Eclipse compiler doesn't recognize it.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scala.util.parsing` was removed from the standard library in Scala 2.11.  Add this to your dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.2"
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the silly question, but where I put the code? thanks! I used Windows without Maven...

Comment: Your build file, either `build.sbt` or `Build.scala`

Comment: There was no such file previously. And I create a build file with the line (just this line)
`libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.2" `
, but it doesn't works... How do I configure the file?

Answer (score 1):

Use this version if you're using Scala 2.13:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.2"
```

The imports are the same, so you can use `import scala.util.parsing.json._` for example.

See [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators) for all the published versions of this lib.